# C# Outlook VSTO contacts duplicating while deleting

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, contacts, outlook-addin

When updating contacts I just delete the old contact and replace it with the new one, because I can't be bothered to check all the fields of all the contacts.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string sTempPath = GetTemporaryDirectory();

        //RequestContacts();
        ExtractContacts(sTempPath);
        ImportContacts(sTempPath);
    }
```

"RequestContacts()" downloads the contacts from the server in a zip to the apps directory.

```
public string GetTemporaryDirectory()
    {
        string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory);
        return tempDirectory;
    }
```

This just finds a temp folder to extract the contacts to and then import from into outlook.

```
private void ExtractContacts(string sExtractPath)
    {
        string sImportPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string sZipPath = sImportPath.Substring(6, sImportPath.Length - 6) + "/contacts.zip";
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sZipPath, sExtractPath);
    }
```

This extracts the downloaded contacts from the zip to the temp folder.

```
private void ImportContacts(string sImportPath)
    {
        var oldContacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>()
            .Where(c => c.ManagerName.Equals("QERP"));
        foreach (var oldContact in oldContacts)
        {
            oldContact.Delete();
        }

        var newContacts = Directory.GetFiles(sImportPath, "*.vcf").Select(Application.Session.OpenSharedItem).Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>();
        foreach (var newContact in newContacts)
        {
            newContact.ManagerName = "QERP";
            newContact.Save();
        }
    }
```

This deletes the old contacts we downloaded, not the contacts that we're not downloaded by this app.

The problem is that it doesn't delete all the contacts. It always deletes half+1 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting from releasing underlying COM objects and avoiding multiple dots in the single line of code. For example:

```
 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items
```

The `Session` property of the Application class returns an instance of the Namespace class which should be released after. The `GetDefaultFolder` method of the Namespace class returns an instance of the MAPIFolder class which should be released as well.

Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

```
    foreach (var oldContact in oldContacts)
    {
        oldContact.Delete();
    }
```

Use the `for` loop instead. It will allows to release underlying COM objects in the code instantly. For deleting Outlook items I'd suggest using the [while](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) loop where you can check out the number of items available or the `for` loop decreasing the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a "foreach" loop when deleting items - you are modifying the collection thus skipping half the items. Use a down "for" loop

```
Outlook.Items items = oldContacts.Items;
for (int i = items.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{
   Outlook.ContactItem contact = items[i] as Outlook.ContactItem; 
   if (contact != null)  //could be a distribution list
   {
      contact.Delete();
   } 
}
```

Comment: oldContacts is a ContactItem, so you can't cast it to Outlook.Item. I fixed it for now by running the foreach in a while loop, but I'll try to find something better like this.

Comment: Change thee declaration of oldContacts to var oldContacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).

Answer (score 0):

It is working and deleting all contacts. I figure out something. 
Help me for clean coding.

```
    private void Contact_Sil()
    {
        var Eski_Contacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>();
        while ( Eski_Contacts.Count()>0)
        {
            Eski_Contacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>();
            foreach (var oldContact in Eski_Contacts)
            {
                oldContact.Delete();
            }                
        }
    }
```